# MSMQ 4.0 Access private queue from a Domain Devmachine a development Docker Container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, msmq

my dev machine is in a Domain and i have a docker container with windows server running in and msmq installed. I want to access a private queue but this is not working from my dev machine. In the docker container i can access the queue.

I followed all the instructions i found in the web.

Docker config:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-Server -All

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR C:\utils
RUN net user guest /active:yes
RUN Set-DtcNetworkSetting -DtcName "local" -Confirm:$false -InboundTransactionsEnabled 1 -OutboundTransactionsEnabled 1 -RemoteClientAccessEnabled 1 -RemoteAdministrationAccessEnabled 1 -XATransactionsEnabled 1 -LUTransactionsEnabled 1 -AuthenticationLevel NoAuth
RUN Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\ -Name AllowNonauthenticatedRPC -Value 1 -Type 'DWORD'
RUN Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\ -Name NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient -Value 1 -Type 'DWORD'
RUN Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\ -Name EveryoneIncludesAnonymous -Value 1 -Type 'DWORD'
ENTRYPOINT ping -t localhost
```

Queues are created with Powershell as a private queue and access is configured

```
New-MsmqQueue -Name "OrderQueue"
Get-MsmqQueue | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" -Allow "DeleteMessage, PeekMessage, ReceiveMessage, WriteMessage, DeleteJournalMessage, ReceiveJournalMessage,SetQueueProperties, GetQueueProperties, DeleteQueue, GetQueuePermissions, GenericWrite, GenericRead,ChangeQueuePermissions, TakeQueueOwnership, FullControl"
Get-MsmqQueue | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "Everyone" -Allow "DeleteMessage, PeekMessage, ReceiveMessage, WriteMessage, DeleteJournalMessage, ReceiveJournalMessage,SetQueueProperties, GetQueueProperties, DeleteQueue, GetQueuePermissions, GenericWrite, GenericRead,ChangeQueuePermissions, TakeQueueOwnership, FullControl"
```

Code(Powershell script) on my dev machine to access the queue:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queuePath = 'FormatName:DIRECT=TCP:<IP of docker container>\private$\OrderQueue'
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath
$queue.GetAllMessages()
```

Any ideas why the exception is coming:
[image]

**EDIT**:
*What i want to to: from my host machine (where docker docker is installed) i want to read messages from a queue from docker container where msmq is running on.
With the provided powershell script you can connect to an external msmq queue.
The ping command in the docker file is only a trick from me that the container is not stopping and running till i stop it. Is there another way to keep the container running ?*

Comment: Have you seen this article? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1278439/Working-with-MSMQ-in-Windows-Docker-Containers

It might provide some clues.

What application on your container is writing to the queue?

Comment: Writing is no problem. Reading is the problem. As you can see with the command "Get-MsmqQueue | Set-MsmqQueueAcl ....." i set the permissions

Comment: What is the docker run command you used? Are the ports open? It clearly timeout, which means the local process is not able to contact the container or process in the container.

Comment: So, the container isn't going to do anything other than the `ENTRYPOINT ping -t localhost` right?  Shouldn't the ENTRYPOINT be executing a command that's waiting to read a message from the queue?  (I may be missing or not understanding something obviously.)

Comment: ping is just used that the container is not stopping. If i dont run a command that is working in the background the container will stop. This is just i little trick.

Comment: Setup is that on the docker container the msmq is running with some queues and on my host (where docker is running) i want to connect to a queue and read the messages. To connect i use the powershell code and before that in a console of the docker container i read the ip address.

So what i want to do is reading messages from my host machine from a docker container where the msmq service is running.